# Determine Git result end/ command finished

Tags: c#, git, process

I developed a C# application which starts the git(.exe) process and asynchronously reads the output lines of the process. Executing a git pull, results in multiple output lines.

E.g.

> Receiving objects:   9% (10/109)
>   Receiving objects:  10% (11/109)
>   Receiving objects:  11% (12/109)
>   Receiving objects:  12% (14/109)

Is it possible to (automatically) determine the end of the result of a Git command, so I can stop the asynchronous read operations and the Git process? Does a Git result contains (a) special character(s) or keyword which represent the end of the result?

Most examples on the web use a console application where the user must manually quit the console to end the git process as well.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit 1:**

Code example

```
gitProcess.Start();

gitProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
gitProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

gitProcess.WaitForExit(200);
gitProcess.Close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait till a process ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147911/wait-till-a-process-ends)

Comment: @max630 This is not a duplicate! I already know how to end a process, but the question is: 'When is a Git command finished, so I can stop the process as well).

Comment: When git program finishes, it stops, as any other command.

Comment: @max630 I added a code example in the OP. If I execute a Git pull command, which takes up to 30 seconds to complete, doesn't the WaitForExit(200) stop the Git process too early?

Comment: I think it should looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13746202/2303202